Prove $- \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+k)^2} = \frac{\zeta(3)}{4}-\frac{\pi^2}{4} \log (2)$

How can I prove that $$- \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+k)^2} = \frac{\zeta(3)}{4}-\frac{\pi^2}{4} \log (2)$$

The problem comes from this MSE post, where the OP wanted to solve integrals of this form
$$f(x) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(t)\ln(1 + t^x)}{t(1-t)}$$
Using the MZIntegrate Mathematica Package, the OP arrived at the result $f(1) = \frac{\zeta(3)}{4}-\frac{\pi^2}{4} \log (2)$. I wanted to mathematically arrive at this result, my attempts are shown below.
Substituting in the taylor series for $\ln(x+1)$, and pulling all constant factors out of the integral, we see that
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(t)\ln(1 + t)}{t(1-t)} dt = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(t)t^n}{t(1-t)} dt = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(t)t^{n-1}}{(1-t)} dt$$
Substituting in the geometric series for $\frac{1}{(1-t)}$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(t)t^{n-1}}{(1-t)} dt = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\int_{0}^1 \ln(t) t^{n-1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}t^k dt$$
Rearranging the sums and integrals, we see that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\int_{0}^1 \ln(t) t^{n-1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}t^k dt = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^1 \ln(t) t^{n+k-1} dt$$
The inner integral evaluates to $-\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}$, which is a standard result.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^1 \ln(t) t^{n+k-1} dt = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}- \frac{1}{(n+k)^2}$$
Hence,
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(t)\ln(1 + t)}{t(1-t)} = - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+k)^2}$$ But how can I continue to show that this sum equals $\frac{\zeta(3)}{4}-\frac{\pi^2}{4} \log (2)$? I am unsure where the denominator of 4 or where $\zeta(3)$ comes from. The inner sum reminds me of the Hurwitz zeta function.
Thanks.

I am sure this integral is quite known and has appeared several times on this site. Regardless, here is an approach:
$$\mathcal{J}=\int _0^1\frac{\log \left(x\right)\log \left(1+x\right)}{x\left(1-x\right)}\:\mathrm{d}x=\int _0^1\frac{\log \left(x\right)}{1-x}\int _0^1\frac{1}{1+xt}\:\mathrm{d}t\:\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=\int _0^1\int _0^1\frac{\log \left(x\right)}{\left(1-x\right)\left(1+xt\right)}\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}t$$
$$=\int _0^1\frac{t}{1+t}\int _0^1\frac{\log \left(x\right)}{1+tx}\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}t+\int _0^1\frac{1}{1+t}\int _0^1\frac{\log \left(x\right)}{1-x}\:\mathrm{d}x\:\mathrm{d}t$$
Note $\int _0^1\frac{\log \left(x\right)}{1+tx}\:\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-t\right)}{t}$
$$\mathcal{J}=\int _0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-t\right)}{1+t}\:\mathrm{d}t-\zeta (2)\int _0^1\frac{1}{1+t}\:\mathrm{d}t$$
Integrate by parts to obtain
$$\mathcal{J}=-\frac{1}{2}\log \left(2\right)\zeta (2)+\int _0^1\frac{\log ^2\left(1+t\right)}{t}\:\mathrm{d}t-\log \left(2\right)\zeta (2)$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\zeta (3)-\frac{3}{2}\log \left(2\right)\zeta (2)$$
Where I used that $\int _0^1\frac{\log ^2\left(1+t\right)}{t}\:\mathrm{d}t=\int _0^1\frac{\log ^2\left(t\right)}{1-t^2}\:\mathrm{d}t-\frac{3}{4}\int _0^1\frac{\log ^2\left(t\right)}{1-t}\:\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{8}\int _0^1\frac{\log ^2\left(t\right)}{1-t}\:\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{4}\zeta (3)$

Thanks. Is there any way I can manipulate the sum to arrive at the same result (without the integral)?

If you must use series, then sooner or later you will find yourself involved with integrals of this kind. Note that $$\int _0^1\frac{\log \left(x\right)\log \left(1+x\right)}{x\left(1-x\right)}:\mathrm{d}x=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{n}\int _0^1\frac{x^{n-1}\log \left(x\right)}{1-x}:\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=\sum {n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{n}\left(\zeta (2)-H{n-1}^{\left(2\right)}\right)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{n}\left(\zeta (2)-H_n^{\left(2\right)}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
